# QGIS: Create dynamic raster over polygon (map sheet lines)

Tags: qgis, modelbuilder

I want to create map sheet lines in A3 format with a scale of 1:2000 over one or more more or less oddly shaped polygons. So far I managed to evenly cover the polygons with my specific map sheet lines (pic. 1). My issue mainly is the efficiency. Everything is covered, which is nice, but I still need to manually delete and move some map sheets. Is there a way to automatically do this, maybe even with rotation of the map sheets to most efficiently cover the area (e.g. like in pic. 2)?

[image: How it looks like]
[image: How it should look like]

Comment: Two related question for the "same" probleme with line and point : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154975/minimising-number-of-dynamic-pages-to-map-scattered-points-using-arcgis-desktop ; https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/384148/optimizing-number-of-printing-pages-in-qgis/384511#384511